# getting occurrence of alphabets in a string, in Matlab

Tags: matlab

i have to do huffman coding on a message read from a file,in Matlab.For that i have to find the probability occurrence of each alphabet in that message.Using that frequency i have to do huffman encoding.Can you please specify how to read a message from the file and store it as a string for the same purpose..Can anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) count:

```
counts = histc(lower(x), 'a':'z');
```

where the output `count` contains the number of occurences for each letter in the message string `x`. For instance, the first element `count(1)` corresponds to the number of occurrences of `a`, `count(2)` corresponds to the number of occurrences of `b`, *etc*...

Also note that this `x` is converted to lowercase o make the counting case insensitive.